# Swift - Decoding a Deeply Nested Dictionary

Tags: swift, google-maps, directions, decodable

I am so close - but I am struggling with a very simple function to allow me to access a data point deeply nested in my JSON. The example I am using is on the Google directions API.

**Sample JSON** (from GMapsAPI):

```
{
  "geocoded_waypoints" : [
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "partial_match" : true,
     "place_id" : "ChIJ960bMolw44kRQcGOlOZQ-r8",
     "types" : [ "premise" ]
  },
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "partial_match" : true,
     "place_id" : "EiMxMTggU2FsZW0gU3QsIEJvc3RvbiwgTUEgMDIxMTMsIFVTQSIaEhgKFAoSCSvDfDSJcOOJEbQanF0WxROfEHY",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  }
],
"routes" : [
  {
     "bounds" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 42.3647252,
           "lng" : -71.0555085
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 42.3644965,
           "lng" : -71.05552419999999
        }
     },
     "copyrights" : "Map data ©2018 Google",
     "legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "82 ft",
              "value" : 25
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "1 min",
              "value" : 11
           },
           "end_address" : "118 Salem St, Boston, MA 02113, USA",
           "end_location" : {
              "lat" : 42.3647252,
              "lng" : -71.0555085
           },
           "start_address" : "115 Salem St, Boston, MA 02113, USA",
           "start_location" : {
              "lat" : 42.3644965,
              "lng" : -71.05552419999999
           },
           "steps" : [
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "82 ft",
                    "value" : 25
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 11
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 42.3647252,
                    "lng" : -71.0555085
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eSalem St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eJerusalem Pl\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "ciqaG~_upLO?]A"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 42.3644965,
                    "lng" : -71.05552419999999
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              }
           ],
           "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
           "via_waypoint" : []
        }
     ],
     "overview_polyline" : {
        "points" : "ciqaG~_upLm@A"
     },
     "summary" : "Salem St",
     "warnings" : [],
     "waypoint_order" : []
  }
  ],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

**Decodable Structure**: To work with this, I am using Decodable. I have been able to access first level nested data (routes.summary), but I am struggling to get further down (for example: routes.legs.duration). My code structure is as follows:

```
struct Directions: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let routes: [Routes]

         enum CodingKeys :String, CodingKey {
              case status, routes
    }

struct Routes: Decodable {
    let summary: String
    let legs: [Legs]

         enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
              case summary, legs
          }
}

struct Legs: Decodable {
    let duration: Duration

          enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
          case duration
          }
    }

struct Duration: Decodable {
        let text: String    

            enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
               case text
            }
        }
```

**Implementation after URL set-up**:

```
      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
          guard let data = data else { return }
          do {   
             let directions = try
             JSONDecoder().decode(Directions.self, from: data)

        for item in directions.routes {
            self.stringoutput = item.summary          
       }
```

After all this, all I want to do is be able to access "text" in the JSON and return that value. The last line in the code is able to successfully return "summary" in the JSON; and I can print(directions) and the whole array/dictionary will return in the debug area, including "text". But I still can't figure out how to do:

x =  directions.routes.legs.duration.text

to make x equal to "1 min"

Would be appreciative of anyone's help.

Edit: What ended up working is Vadian's struct keys below and the following for in loop:

```
                for item in directions.routes {
                    print(item.summary)
                    self.direct = item.summary
                    for items in item.legs {
                        self.stringoutput = items.duration.text
                        print(items.duration.text)
                        }
```

Cheers!

Comment: *trimmed it down* is not helpful as well as this unreadable mess of structs. Please format the code properly and remove unnecessary empty lines.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the code formatting and updated the JSON. Made some updates which hopefully make it more readable - apologies for the rookie error.

Comment: Does just doing `x = item.duration.text`  in your for loop work?

Comment: This `x = directions.routes.legs.duration.text` won't work as `Legs` is an array. So you will have to do something like this `x = directions.routes.legs[0].duration.text`.

Comment: I would recommend you put the **entire** JSON you're seeking help with in there. If you've got an endpoint you can disclose that kicks back the JSON, I personally prefer that, as I can dump it in Postman and see what comes back with my own eyes.

Comment: SirCxyrtyx - unfortunately tried but gives error "Value of Type 'Directions.Routes has no member duration.

Comment: Kathayatnk - interesting, I am playing around with new formatting - unfortunately, keep getting the kickback Directions.Routes has no member 'legs'. Not sure why it cannot be found.

Comment: Adrian - added the full JSON, but not sure I understand what you mean: "If you've got an endpoint you can disclose that kicks back the JSON"

Comment: Use this online tool for conveting JSON to Struct: http://www.json4swift.com/ Iam using this only. working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These structs don't decode all keys, but it's a starting point.

If keys and struct members have the same name you don't need to specify `CodingKeys`

```
struct Directions: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let routes: [Route]
}

struct Route: Decodable {
    let summary: String
    let legs: [Leg]
}

struct Leg: Decodable {
    let duration : TextValue
    let distance : TextValue
    let endAddress : String
    let endLocation : Location
    let startAddress : String
    let startLocation : Location
    let steps : [Step]
}

struct TextValue: Decodable {
    let text: String
    let value : Int
}

struct Location: Decodable {
    let lat, lng : Double
}

struct Step: Decodable {
    let duration : TextValue
    let distance : TextValue
    let endLocation : Location
    let startLocation : Location
    let htmlInstructions : String
    let travelMode : String
}
```

To decode the *snake_cased* keys properly you have to add the appropriate key decoding strategy

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

To access the arrays (`[]`) you have to get an item by index

```
step[0]
```

or iterate the array with a loop

```
for step in steps {}
```

Comment: Vadian, thank you for your help. I ended up using your code and what worked for me was the for in loop in my edited main post. Thank you!